# spring redirecting a external url and status

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC, I need to launch an application by giving the url for authentication, if it is success then set the attribute as success otherwise failure.

I have tried with this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String dataMappings(Model model) throws Exception {
    model.addAttribute("status","status Don't Know here");
    return "redirect:"+"http://localhost:8292/auth";
}
```

Here this launches my another `http://localhost:8292/auth`, but the problem is I need to know authentication success or failure and set the status in set attribute and display in UI.
How do I handle this?

Comment: Can you clarify this question a bit, you want to redirect to another external URL if the Spring MVC authentication is successful?

Answer (score 0):

IMO you shouldn't be handling the redirect in your controller. Instead of returning `String`consider returning `ModelAndView`. 
 
 Configure a view resolver and create appropriate views viz. success and failure. Then in the view you should do the redirect.
 
The attributte you want to set should / can be done at controller and will be part of `Model`